# Missing object from HttpContext session in custom IHttpModule

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule, ihttpmodule

I am writing custom IHttpModule. I need to manage HttpContext session object. To enable that I have added custom IHttpHandler that is inherited from IRequiresSessionState. Then I can access session (it is not null). I am writing logic in PreRequestHandlerExecute after handler execution, to have session reachable.

Then I have faced with problem. When I add something to session that is not saved/stored there. With each successive request in my module, I can not find object that I have added to the session.

Is is possible to write persistently to session from custom modules or I am missing something ?

EDITED -> R.Isajev :

```
public class CustomFederationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // TODO
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostAcquireRequestState += Application_PostAcquireRequestState;
        context.PostMapRequestHandler += Application_PostMapRequestHandler;
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute;

        context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
        context.Error += OnErrorOccured;
    }

    private void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Session ID : " + HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID);
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Isajev"] == null)
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Isajev"] = "Rastko Isajev";
    }


    private void OnEndRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is HttpApplication)
        {
            HttpResponse response = (sender as HttpApplication).Response;
            int statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        }
    }

    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Application_PostMapRequestHandler(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;

        if (app.Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState || app.Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState)
        {
            // no need to replace the current handler
            return;
        }

        // swap the current handler
        app.Context.Handler = new MyHttpHandler(app.Context.Handler);
    }

    void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;

        MyHttpHandler resourceHttpHandler = HttpContext.Current.Handler as MyHttpHandler;

        if (resourceHttpHandler != null)
        {
            // set the original handler back
            HttpContext.Current.Handler = resourceHttpHandler.OriginalHandler;
        }

        // -> at this point session state should be available
        Debug.Assert(app.Session != null, "it did not work :(");
    }


    private void OnErrorOccured(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error occured ! \n" + e.ToString());
    }

    // A temp handler used to force the SessionStateModule to load session state
    public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        internal readonly IHttpHandler OriginalHandler;

        public MyHttpHandler(IHttpHandler originalHandler)
        {
            OriginalHandler = originalHandler;
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            // do not worry, ProcessRequest() will not be called, but let's be safe
            throw new InvalidOperationException("MyHttpHandler cannot process requests.");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            // IsReusable must be set to false since class has a member!
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

In custom module I am using custom handler with purpose to enable session usage in module, because originally it is sessionless. In this sample 'Isajev' is added with first call into session. In the next one call from the same user and browser it is not present in session.

Regards,
Rastko

Comment: are you sure that request to the module is from the same user ?

Comment: yes, yes I am testing with same user from the same browser

Comment: did you check is the SessionID the same ?

Comment: yes, same session id is coming

Comment: hm, it should work :), could you show us some source ? Did you try to make simple module that sets session ?

Comment: Well, your example works for me, I created new ASP.NET 4.5 app in VS 2012, using IIS Express as web server and declare HttpModule in web.config under system.webServer/modules. And each new request has session value. Did you test this under IIS or VS dev server ?

Comment: Thank you Antonio. This is also asp.net 4.5 app, developed under VS 2012. It is deployed and tested with IIS. It is really strange.